# How can I resolve a 'ld: .eh_frame_hdr refers to overlapping FDEs' error during final linking on CentOS with binutils 2.40?

Tags: linux, linker, centos, ld, binutils

I am trying to build a project with various third party libraries like cryptopp, openssl, curl, to name a few.

Details :

OS : CentOS-5.11
GCC : 12.3.0
binutils : 2.40 (./configure --prefix= --enable-gprofng=no)

I get this error during the final link :

```
ld: .eh_frame_hdr refers to overlapping FDEs
ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Unfortunately, I cannot share any code that I am compiling.

Any suggestions/tips appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.